# grid not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I'm using dojo grid to show data, issue is latest data is not shown in the grid.
Below is the sample code:

home.jsp:

```
      dojo.ready(function(){

                    mystore=new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/displayData.htm"});
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Put in no-cache headers, the strongest ones possible because IE is stubborn and likes to insist on caching.

Comment: @developerwjk, i tried but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding no-cache headers to displayData is not working, I would try adding a random parameter to the Ajax call.  I'm assuming here that this line is like an Ajax call.

```
mystore=new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/displayData.htm?r="+Math.random()});
```

This will cause IE to see the call as unique. It will still cache it, but should never read the cache unless your random number happens to repeat. You don't have to actually do anything with the parameter on the server-side.